# jQuery change cursor - happening at end of function

Tags: jquery, css

I am looking to change the cursor when a function is called to search through XML to match a word so the user knows something is happening.

This is the function:

```
    function searchResults(query) {
      $("body").css("cursor", "wait");
      var temp = "\\b" + query + "\\b";
      var regex_query = new RegExp(temp, "gi");
      var currentLine;
      var num_matching_lines = 0;
      var searchCount = 0;
      var matchesLine;
      $("#mainOutput, #searhResults").empty();
      $("LINE", currentContext).each(function () {
        var line = this;
        currentLine = $(this).text();
        matchesLine = currentLine.replace(regex_query, '<span class="query_match">' + query + '</span>');
        if (currentLine.search(regex_query) > 0) {
          searchCount = searchCount + currentLine.match(regex_query).length;
          $('#sideInfo>ul').empty();
          num_matching_lines++
          $("#mainOutput").append("<br /><p class='speaker_match indent'>"+  $(line).parent().find('SPEAKER').text() +"</p>");
          $("#mainOutput").append("<p class='act_match indent'>"+  $(line).parent().parent().parent().children(':first-child').text()+"</p>");
          $("#mainOutput").append("<p class='scene_match indent'>"+  $(line).parent().parent().children(':first-child').text() +"</p>");
          $("#mainOutput").append("<p class='pad'>" + matchesLine + "</p>");
          $("#mainOutput").append("<br><hr />");
        }   
      });
      $("#searhResults").append("<p>Found " + query + " in " + num_matching_lines + " lines</p>");
      $("#searhResults").append("<p>Found " + query + " " + searchCount + " times</p>");
      $("body").css("cursor", "default");
    }
```

It is called by either of these actions:

```
  $("#term_search").keypress(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) searchResults($("#term_search").val()); 
  });

  $('#term-search-btn').click(function () {
    searchResults($("#term_search").val());
  });
```

The problem is that the cursor changes to the wait symbol after the search in complete and then does not change back to default, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're likely suffering from two problems:

1. If your code doesn't cede control back to the JS event loop, it's quite likely that any DOM changes you make will not be visible immediately.  A possible work around is to change the cursor, and then use a `setTimeout(func, 0)` to pass control back to the event loop, which can then render DOM updates and then call your `func` to complete your processing.
2. Some browsers don't update cursor shapes until the mouse moves.  I know of no work around for that.